# WordNet: semantic relationship between different parts of the same object

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, wordnet

I have a question on "WordNet: semantic relationship between different parts of the same object". The following is a paragraph I quoted from wikipedia:

> For example, Holonymy/Meronymy defines the relationship between a term
>   denoting the whole and a term denoting a part of, or a member of, the
>   whole. That is,
>
> 'X' is a holonym of 'Y' if Ys are parts of Xs, or 'X' is a holonym of
>   'Y' if Ys are members of Xs.

Then, I want to know, if X and Y are different parts of the same object, what is the semantic relationship between X and Y?

For example, a keyboard and a mouse are all parts of a computer. What is the semantic relationship between a keyboard and a mouse?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that relation is something you, as a Wordnet developer, create.  If you are developing Wordnet in your own language, then you might need to define some kind of specific relations. So, **don't expect to have all kinds of relation in Wordnet by default**.

May be the *word* you are looking for is only **Sibling**, but as far as I remember, **there is no** specific relation for *two sibling Meronyms*. If there is such thing, then it is a really bad anomaly in database, because from one side we collect Meronyms/Holonyms, and from other side we collect siblings of them which is something extra. In this case you need to use a **query**, which is:

```
For a given X, extract all its Holonyms with related Meronyms of those Holonyms
```

Comment: Well, I think you are on the right side! You only need to write SQL query for that purpose

Comment: I am trying to derive indoor scene category from the objects that can be found in this scene. 
For example, if an indoor scene contains a bed, then I am quite sure this scene depicts a bedroom rather than a meeting room. In this case, even if there is a pillow on the bed, I do not need to draw on the information of a pillow on the bed. Therefore, there is kind of a relationship between a pillow and a bed, i.e. they both are parts of a bedroom. They are considered siblings. 
You can infer the existence of a sibling given another sibling. Information provided by siblings are redundant.